# How to fix this error AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'timer_left'?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a timer on tkinter and I started getting --- AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'timer_left'. I don't know what to do with it, please help
There is my file:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

import time
import datetime


class Timer(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Таймер'
        self.geometry = '600x250'

        self.lbl = ttk.Label(self, text='Таймер')
        self.lbl.grid(column=3, row=0, pady=20)

        self.hours = ttk.Label(self, text='Часов: ', width=10)
        self.hours.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.minutes = ttk.Label(self, text='Минут: ', width=10)
        self.minutes.grid(column=2, row=1)
        self.seconds = ttk.Label(self, text='Секунд: ', width=10)
        self.seconds.grid(column=4, row=1)

        try:
            self.timer_hours = ttk.Entry(self, width=10)
            self.timer_minutes = ttk.Entry(self, width=10)
            self.timer_seconds = ttk.Entry(self, width=10)
        except ValueError:
            self.timer_hours = ttk.Entry(self, width=10)
            self.timer_minutes = ttk.Entry(self, width=10)
            self.timer_seconds = ttk.Entry(self, width=10)

        self.timer_hours.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.timer_minutes.grid(column=3, row=1)
        self.timer_seconds.grid(column=5, row=1)

        self.start = ttk.Button(self, text='Запустить таймер', command=self.countdown)
        self.start.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=10)

        self.timer = ttk.Label(self, text=str(self.timer_left), width=10)
        self.timer.grid(row=3, column=3, pady=25)

    def countdown(self):
        h = int(self.timer_hours.get())
        m = int(self.timer_minutes.get())
        s = int(self.timer_seconds.get())
        total_seconds = h * 3600 + m * 60 + s

        while total_seconds > 0:
            self.timer_left = datetime.timedelta(seconds=total_seconds)

            time.sleep(1)

            total_seconds -= 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    timer = Timer()
    timer.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self.timer_left` is only defined once `self.countdown` is executed. Instead set the label text to be `0` and then update it later with `self.timer.config(text=self.timer_left)`. But you will still face the GUI to freeze because `time.sleep` will block the `mainloop`

Comment: Thanks,it works, but the time that I set instantly calculated up to 1 second

Comment: That is what I said, learn about `self.after()` method and use it